# Installing bxSlider Jquery plugin in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses on Internet an now I decided to build a Wordpress theme so like this I can continue learning from the practice.

I decided to make an image slider, so for this I decided to install a Jquery plugin. I know that I can install a wordpress plugin but I think that it's convenient to learn how to install a Jquery plugin too for many reasons.

I followed these steps to install the [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) plugin, but unfortunately there is something that it's not ok and it makes my plugin doesn't work:

1) **Functions.php:** I loaded all the files that I need

```
function loadbxslider() {

    wp_enqueue_style('bxstyle', '/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('bxscript', '/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'));

}

add_action('init', 'loadbxslider');
```

**2) Header.php:** I wrote this before `<?php wp_head(); ?>`:

```
<!--?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?-->
<!--?php wp_head(); ?-->
```

And this inmediately after `<?php wp_head(); ?>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#slidebx').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    infiniteLoop: true,
    speed: 2000,
    pause: 8000,
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: true
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

So the first part of my header.php is like this:

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>


    <!--?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?-->
    <!--?php wp_head(); ?-->

    <?php wp_head(); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#slidebx').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    infiniteLoop: true,
    speed: 2000,
    pause: 8000,
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: true
  });
});
// ]]></script>


</script>
</head>
```

**3) bxSlider inside my content:** using the id slidebx

```
<div id="slidebx">
  <div><?php the_field('image1'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image2'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image3'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image4'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image5'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image6'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image7'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image8'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image9'); ?></div>
  <div><?php the_field('image10'); ?></div>
</div>
```

I have a week trying to discover why this plugin doesn't work. If you have some suggestion would be good for my learning process.